# pyqt Qtextbrowser update

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextbrowser

```
def sort_domain():
    if self.cb1.isChecked():
        for line in f:
            line= line.strip()
            if line.endswith('.com') is True:
                self.textBrowser.append(line)
            else:
                pass
    elif not self.cb1.isChecked() and not self.cb2.isChecked():
        for line in f:
            line=line.strip()
            self.textBrowser.append(line)
    if self.cb2.isChecked():
        for line in f:
            line= line.strip()
            if line.endswith('.net') is True:
                self.textBrowser.append(line)
            else:
                pass
    elif not self.cb1.isChecked() and not self.cb2.isChecked():
        for line in f:
            line=line.strip()
            self.textBrowser.append(line)

self.btn2.clicked.connect(sort_domain)
```

If I checked cb1 and cb2 ((checkbox1 and chekbok2))
the results are all domains with extension .com  only.

What is the correct way to write a function to show all Domains when you press the chekBox1 ".com" and chekBox2 ".net"?

[image: code and window]

Comment: Pictures  http://i.stack.imgur.com/rdnjo.png

Comment: If this image helps your question, you should add it in the text of your question. You can edit your question after publishing it as many times as you want :)

Comment: You say "my Question:" but then I don't see a question.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is not really efficient: it reads the contents of the file more than once. And this is also the issue of your program. After the first for-loop the file object points to the end of the file and to make it work you'd have to seek to the start again: `f.seek(0)`